# jQuery: get sum of values of all selects with same class

Tags: jquery, html, class

I have an HTML form with multiple selects that all have the same class. 
Out of these only one appears at a time depending on previous selections and thus only one of them can have a value at a time.

What is the proper / best way to get the value of all these selects put together ?

**They look like this:**

```
<select class="formField" id="input1"> ... list of options ... </select>
<select class="formField" id="input2"> ... list of options ... </select>
<select class="formField" id="input3"> ... list of options ... </select>
```

**Would the following be correct in this case ?**

```
$('.formField').val();
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `.each()` to iterate through those elements and add their value in a separate variable.

Try this,

```
var xSum = 0;

$('.formField').each(function(){
  xSum += parseInt($(this).val());
 })

alert(xSum);
```

For your reference read this : [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

**Update**

The following code will concatenate the values.

```
var xResultString = '';

$('.formField').each(function(){
  xResultString += $.trim($(this).val());
 })

alert(xResultString);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cnb54/)

Comment: Man you were quick! Good job.

Comment: Thanks ! The values of my select options only contain text. I guess I would not need parseInt then, right ? How would I do it then ?

Comment: @user2571510 so you want to concatenate it right.? I misunderstood with that word sum.

Comment: Thats perfect - exactly what I was looking for ! Sorry for the misleading description.

Answer (score 2):

You need a iterate through all of them.
This script will concatenate all the strings.

```
var selectValues = "";

$('.formField').each(function () {
  selectValues += $(this).val();
});

console.log(selectValues);
```